# How to set the values for HatchBrush from config file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

In my class, i have used the following code

```
   'Draw text 
        hb = New HatchBrush(HatchStyle.LargeConfetti, Color.LightGray, Color.DarkGray)
```

Now i would like to get the values assigned to HatchBrush from an xml file as follows, instead of directly assigning it in the class as above. Because there is a need to change the colors frequently.

```
  <hatchstyle>HatchStyle.LargeGrid</hatchstyle>
  <forecolor>Color.LightGray</forecolor>
  <backcolor>Color.Black</backcolor>
```

And in my class, i have the values of all the three nodes in a string. But how do i assign these string values to my HatchBrush( _ , _ , _ ) ??

I know that these string values cannot be directly assigned to HatchBrush, but i get the values from xml as string. How do i cast it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim style As String = "LargeConfetti" ' value from xml
Dim hs As HatchStyle = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(HatchStyle), style), HatchStyle)

Dim hb = New HatchBrush(hs, Color.LightGray, Color.DarkGray)
```

For the colors, same method but use `Color` enum instead of `HatchStyle`.